# Selectize.js on Appended Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I am currently trying to append new  elements by clicking a button with a class of "add" to a parent . I want these appended elements to get the functionalities of [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) after being appended but somehow it's not working. Here is my javascript code:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
var newSelectize = '<select id="input-tags"></select>';
var selectizeWrapper =$(this).parent().find('.selectize-wrapper');
var lastSelectize = selectizeWrapper.find('#input-tags').last();

selectizeWrapper.append(newSelectize);
lastSelectize.selectize({
     delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    searchField: 'item'
    });
});
```

Here is my sample [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wh6Nx/41/)

Comment: `selectizeWrapper.find('#input-tags').last();` this line does not get the last appended element. And two elements cannot have same Id. You have to change the Id of appended elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/wh6Nx/42/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="demo">
    <div class="selectize-wrapper">
        <input type="text" value="test" class="elements demo-default selectized" id="input-tags" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Add" class="add">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.add').click(function(){
var newSelectize = '<select id="input-tags" class="elements"></select>';
var selectizeWrapper =$(this).parent().find('.selectize-wrapper');


selectizeWrapper.append(newSelectize);
var lastSelectize = selectizeWrapper.find('.elements').last();
console.log(lastSelectize);
lastSelectize.selectize({
     delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    searchField: 'item'
    });
});
```

---

### Comments

1. Instead of similar ID's I have added a common class called **elements**.
2. The line var `lastSelectize = selectizeWrapper.find('.elements').last();` should execute after you append the new html `selectizeWrapper.append(newSelectize);` ; else it is of no use.